# What is the general equation of finding position x of images when they are aligned at center?

Tags: geometry

Suppose I have an image a1 and the anchor point is at center of image, when it is aligned at centre, the position is 0,0

[image]

When another image a2 is added and a1 and a2 together are aligned at center, a1 shifts left and position x becomes -a2.width/2,while a2 shifts right and the position x becomes a1.width/2

[image]

but the problem is, I just find position of a1 and a2 by experiment, I do not know the general formula of finding x position of each image, how about if I have a1,a2,a3,a4... with different width?

How can I find their x position shift?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can always get the "leftest" $x$ coordinate by

$$x_0=\frac{-\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}2$$. 
The other $x$ coordinates are $x_i=x_0+\sum_{l=1}^i x_l$

```
----------------------------
| a1    |    a2    |  a3   |
----------------------------
x0      x1         x2      x3
```